# MySQL Function IF() do not return the value that i declare

Tags: mysql

> i want my function to return "INC" when put "INC" inside the function parameters

```
SELECT getEquivalentGrade('INC');
```

> Output: INC

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `nmsc_scholarship_db`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `getEquivalentGrade`$$

CREATE DEFINER =`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getEquivalentGrade`(grade CHAR(5))
  RETURNS CHAR(5)
  CHARSET latin1
  BEGIN
    DECLARE equivalent_grade CHAR(5);

    IF (grade > 100)
    THEN
      SET equivalent_grade = '1';

    ELSEIF (grade < 69)
      THEN
        SET equivalent_grade = '5';

    ELSEIF (grade = 'INC')
      THEN
        SET equivalent_grade = grade;

    ELSE
      SET equivalent_grade = (SELECT equivalent_grade.`equivgrade`
                              FROM equivalent_grade
                              WHERE equivalent_grade.`fromgrade` <= grade AND equivalent_grade.`tograde` >= grade);

    END IF;
    RETURN equivalent_grade;
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> **now, if i will execute this function, this is what i get.**

```
SELECT getEquivalentGrade('INC');
```

> **Output: 5**

Comment: i just already solve it.

Comment: i put the 
elseif grade = 'inc' then
set equivalent_grade = grade;

ahead to 
elseif grade < 69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the INC to the TOP

```
IF (grade='INC') THEN
SET equivalent_grade = grade;

ELSEIF (grade > 100) THEN
SET equivalent_grade = '1';

ELSEIF (grade < 69) THEN
SET equivalent_grade = '5';

ELSE
SET equivalent_grade = (SELECT equivalent_grade.`equivgrade` FROM equivalent_grade WHERE equivalent_grade.`fromgrade`<= grade AND equivalent_grade.`tograde`>= grade);
```

And you should research how IFELSE work.
Condition was working like it will stop/goto ENDIF.. IF** the condition **true** was meet, or they will keep finding till the latest **IF**